# Create an Doctrine/Symfony entity manually from an existing SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine, entity, uniqueidentifier

I have a table in SQL Server that I need to create an entity for in Symfony. I don't want to reverse engineer the entire database because there are entities already created that I don't want to overwrite. I have written a few entities successfully, but there is one table that is causing problems. It has a primary and a foreign key stored as Unique Identifiers. Below is the code I am using to create the ID property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="MembID", type="guid")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $id;
```

And here is my getter:

```
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return guid 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

This works for when my primary key is an integer but not a GUID. When I try to load the page I get a HTTP ERROR 500. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, could you provide the full error message?

Comment: The HTTP ERROR 500 is all I get. I can tell that it bombs in the controller at the following line of code: $entities = $em->getRepository('GFWebsiteBundle:Member')->findAll();

Comment: checks your `dev.log` file then, we need more information to know where is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the dev.log file and there was no error message shown, but the entries did seem to just cut off mid stream. So I tried another table with a UniqueIdentifier and got a message stating something like I reached a maximum data cap. I can't give the exact error message because I can't recreate it. But the problem was just too much data trying to load. I was successful in getting a single record from the database.

Thanks to Yonel for pointing me in the right direction. I'll send an upvote as soon as I figure out how.